# How to fix HTML z-index layer ordering in IE7?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a popup that is displayed above the link when I hover over a link. There is an image just above the link so the problem is that in ie7 the popup is appearing under the image. It works well in IE8 and Firefox.

The problem that I want to fix is found on this page: http://www.kandscars.com/servicecontracts.php. If you hover over "Class One" then hover over "Cars In This Class".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some debugging and it turns it's the opacity filter for IE on the `<div class="cover boxcaption">` that's causing the cut off, not the image.

I couldn't get it working with the filter applied so the only thing I can suggest that will fix it is to use a semi-transparent background png instead of using css to apply the transparency.

Comment: thanks for the tip, you are right! but how can i create this png to replace the opacity property?

Comment: If you have Photoshop, create a 1px by 1px semi-transparent picture of the color you want (by lowering it's opacity) and then select Save for Web & Devices from the File menu, select PNG-24 in the dropdown and make sure Transparency is checked then save it. Now all you have to do is set the picture and the background-image for the divs you want. (Make sure you don't specify a background-color or no-repeat)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the z-order to 1 in the css class of the popup. I found the same problem a couple of months ago!

Comment: Sorry I don't know the answer then. Setting the z-index fixed it for me!